# I can't access my visualforce page in public through site

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I create Two visualforce page name like A1 & B1. Both pages are enabled in site. Page A1 has a ouputlink if click that link page will redirect to B1.
A1 is the Active Site Home Page.if click link in the page they can't redirect to page B1. They require authorization.

Comment: Can you add the Visualforce for the link to your question? Sites add an extra element to URLs.

Comment: Sometimes the 'Require Authorization' page appears if there is an exception when running the page. Do each of the pages work inside Salesforce when running as a user? i.e. load page a1 and then see if link to b1. If this works then there maybe a problem with access rights to the data behind for the 'Site User' or the VF page or the output link is incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable access to this page for public access
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the object and fields that is being accessed by the page is accessible to the Guest User.

Answer (score 1):

Always use [relative URLs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) for linking visualforce pages.

Answer (score -4):

I got solution actually i given  salesforce instance  url in that link now i changed and give my site url in that  link.

**Before**

Click me

**after**:

Click me